Bool not becoming false in Unity
I am trying to create a working attack animation for a 2D game that's for a school project. I noticed that the attack animation continuosly loops with the idle animation. The attack animation stops running if I do the Jump animation for some reason. I noticed wthat my "isAttacking" bool does not become false automatically even when I followed a YouTube tutorial fully. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    bool isGrounded;
    
    [SerializeField] Transform groundCheck;

    [SerializeField] private float runSpeed = 15f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpSpeed = 5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Physics2D.Linecast(transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground")))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(runSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);

            if (isGrounded)
                animator.Play("Player1_run");

            spriteRenderer.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(-runSpeed, rb2d.velocity.y);

            if (isGrounded)
                animator.Play("Player1_run");

            spriteRenderer.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isGrounded)
                animator.Play("Player1_idle");

            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb2d.velocity.y);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("w") && isGrounded)
        {
            rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(rb2d.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
            animator.Play("Player1_jump");
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
        {
            animator.SetBool("isAttacking", true);
        }
    }

    public void endAtack()
    {
        animator.SetBool("isAttacking", false);
    }
}



Maybe there's something I'm not aware of due to being unfamiliar with Unity but I don't see where you're using the value of "isAttacking" or where you're calling endAttack.

it's hard to say without the animator's tree, I advise you to check if the character comes out of the jump state and goes into the idle state. And it is better to use Trigger instead of bool on the attack, calling the function at the end of the animation is not stable. If the animation is interrupted, the function will never be called

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
